# What is the difference between two line of code in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know what is the `?`, `!!`, or `==` in kotlin  I really confuse the exact difference between them, below I have line of code, what is the difference between both line of code?

```
 users.find { it.id != userId }?.name 

 users.find { it.id == userId }!!.name
```

Comment: For many languages descendants of C (like Java and Kotlin are) in the ALGOL family tree, the `!=` is *not equal*, and `==` is *equal*. Just about any tutorial or beginners guide or book should have had that information.

Comment: learning isn't a problem, but in the time it took you to write this post you could have found several answers online already for this, besides, you said this is in your own code already, so you wrote this without knowing what it does ? how do you know it exists but you don't know what it does ?

Comment: If you have written the code yourself, you should really know what it means. And if you copied it from somewhere else and don't know what it means, then you have fallen into the [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) trap which isn't good. If you have forgotten about something this basic, then perhaps take it as a sign to refresh your knowledge? Find a decent book, tutorial or perhaps even a class to take, to refresh and relearn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

== operator is used to check whether the contents of 2 variables match example the user.id and it.id in your code.

!= is used when we want to check whether the contents do not match they are opposite to each other.

**Update after edit** -
Assuming the `users` is a list or one of the kotlin collection the first LOC finds the first user from the collection that has same id as userId then if there is such a user ie the ? returns some object then gets the name of same.

The second LOC has a condition that is exactly opposite it finds the first user that does not have the same id and provides its name.

Comment: @understand very well tnx